# When linking, is there something between "grab what you need" and "grab all" (-Wl,--whole-archive)?

Tags: c++, linker, ld, abstract-factory, static-block

I have this library which involves some static initialization code which needs to run before `main()`. It all works well if you just compile all of the translation units together, but it doesn't work if I provide a static library (`.a` file) and have users link their application against it - the linker simply ignores the symbols which do my static initialization.

Alternatively, I can make the linker pick up *everything* in the static library, if I specify the `-Wl,--whole-archive` option to GCC, i.e. specify the `--whole-archive` option to GNU link.

But is there some middle ground? Can I mark some symbols and make the linker always pick them up for the executable, while the rest of the symbols are added only when needed?

*Motivation:* I use some [static blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298503/1593077) to register classes in a factory; I want to make my code available as a (non-dynamic) library, without the user code having to perform any "magic incantation" for the factory to be populated.

Some related questions:

- [How to force include static objects from a static library in C++ (MSVC 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336778/how-to-force-include-static-objects-from-a-static-library-in-c-msvc-11)
- [How to force gcc to link unreferenced, static C++ objects from a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767925/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-unreferenced-static-c-objects-from-a-library)
- [How to force gcc to link an unused static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116420/how-to-force-gcc-to-link-an-unused-static-library?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Did you ever find an alternative to `--whole-archive`?

Comment: @tmm1: No, I sort of gave up on it.

Comment: I guess `--undefined` is the only other solution. More details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47186765/332798

Answer (score 2):

You can force the linker to keep a given function (and naturally, all code that is called from this function). Add `-u my_function` to the link command. Many build systems let static libraries to 'export' the build settings to those who use them. E.g., for Android **ndk-build** framework, you can specify something like

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := the_best_static_library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libfoo.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDFLAGS := -u my_function
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

in your module **Android.mk**. People reuse it by adding to their **Android.mk** the simple statement

```
$(call import-module,third_party/the_best_static_library)
```

**N.B.** For this approach to work, `my_function()` cannot be declared `static`. If some symbol is declared as static at the file scope, then the linker guess not know it by name at all. Luckily, if it is referenced in some code that the linker decides to keep, then it will also not get stripped off. Furthermore, unless you make a [special effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6770305/192373), the linker will strip or keep whole compilation units (a.k.a. C files). Thus, it is usually [enough](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_na.html#mac) to "anchor" a dummy function to keep many functions and data.

Comment: (1) What part of this example is specific to Android? Does GNU ld respect all these flags? (2) about `static` - you mean not declaring it static at file scope, right? That would actually be problematic for me... but still, +1 for now and when I get a chance to try it I'll accept.

Comment: I expanded the answer about **statuc**. Regarding the linker flag, it is available on any gcc based toolchain, as far as I know. The Android specific stuff is how you distribute the knowledge to users of your static library. How do you help them to access your header files? How do you teach them that your code depends on some third party prebuilt libraries?